# implementing a flip-flop with concurrent statement

Tags: concurrency, vhdl

It is stated in VHDL programming that for combinational circuits, concurrent statements are used while for sequential circuits, both concurrent and sequential statements are applicable. Now the question is:

What will happen if I write a sequential code in a concurrent form? For example, I don't use `process` and write a flip flop with `when..else`

```
architecture x of y is
begin
   q <= '0' when rst=1 else
        d   when (clock'event and clock='1') else
        q;
end;
```

Is that a correct and synesthesizable code? If it is an incorrect code, what is wrong with that exactly (apart form syntax errors)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say: "It is stated in VHDL programming that for combinational circuits, concurrent statements are used while for sequential circuits, both concurrent and sequential statements are applicable.". That is simply not true. You can model both combinational and sequential code using either concurrent or sequential statements.

It is unusual to model sequential logic using concurrent statements. (I say that because I see a lot of other people's code in my job and I almost never see it). However, it is possible. Your code does have a syntax error and a more fundamental error. This modified version of your code synthesises to a rising-edge triggered flip-flop with an asynchronous, active-high reset, as you expected:

```
q <= '0' when rst='1' else
      d  when clock'event and clock='1';
```

The syntax error was that you had `rst=1` instead of `rst='1'`. The more fundamental error was that you don't need the `else q`. This is unnecessary, because signals in VHDL retain the value previously assigned until a new value is assigned. Therefore, in VHDL code modelling sequential logic, it is *never* necessary to write `q <= q` (or its equivalent). In your case, in the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I constructed `q` was an output and so your `else q` gave a syntax error because you cannot read outputs.

Here's the MCVE:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity concurrent_flop is
  port (clock, rst, d : in  std_logic;
        q             : out std_logic);
end entity concurrent_flop;

architecture concurrent_flop of concurrent_flop is
begin
   q <= '0' when rst='1' else
         d  when clock'event and clock='1';
end architecture concurrent_flop;
```

I wrote an MCVE to check what I was about to say was correct. You could have done the same. Doing so is a great way of learning VHDL. EDA Playground is often a good place to try things out (shameless plug), but was no good in this case, because one cannot synthesise VHDL on EDA Playground.

Comment: So can you explain a bit more on why it is unusual? If it is OK why it is unusual? Is there any example to see that a concurrent implementation of a sequential circuit fails to synthesis or fails to work?

Comment: Usually experienced VHDL designers will incorporate their combinational logic in the same process as their sequential logic. You can only code fairly simple combinational logic using concurrent statements, so, if you coded your sequential logic using concurrent statements, you would be limiting yourself. Also, unless the combinational logic leads to code with a regular structure, concurrent statements can look a mess and be hard to read/debug. However, I suspect the main reason is fashion and/or taste.